# How get Tab click to ALWAYS open the Tab's page, without immediately showing item detail (if detail was previously open)?

Tags: xamarin.forms

I have  3 pages MainPage , ListPage and ItemPage witch is opened from ListPage on item click. In tabbar I want to switch between the MainPage and ListPage and everything looks fine untill I open list item detail (ItemPage). After ItemPage tab is switching now between  MainPage nad ItemPage   instead  of  MainPage and ListPage.

How to force tab to open/recreate  ALWAYS ListPage ?

```xml
<TabBar x:Name="BottomTabs"  >
    <Tab Title="Main" x:Name="homeTabe" Icon="icon_car.png">
        <ShellContent ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:MainPage}" />
    </Tab>
    <Tab Title="List" Icon="icon_map.png">
        <ShellContent ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:ListPage}" />
    </Tab>
</TabBar>
```

Comment: this is normal behavior.  If the user navigates to a child page of a tab, switches tabs, and the switches back, they should remain to the same child of the tab that they had previously navigated to

Comment: @Jason , I'm not saying that this is some kind of error, but in my case client wants to avoid this behavior so MainPage and ListPage should ALWAYS start like they are starting first time.
In android this can be easily handled in an Activity by replacing Fragment, but in Xamarin. Forms I can't find what method in ListPage is responsible for this behavior

Comment: you probably need to handle it in the TabbedPage - there is an event that fires when the selected tab changes

Comment: I don't see such event in  Xamarin.Forms.TabBar  class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just override method `OnDisappearing` in your `ItemPage` and pop up this page while tabs is switching.

You can refer to the following code:

```
    protected override void OnDisappearing()
    {
        base.OnDisappearing();

        Navigation.PopAsync();
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can maybe give a try to the following methods by overriding them inside your pages :

`protected override void OnAppearing()`

`protected override void OnDisappearing()`

And then implement the logic you want for your behavior.